# Rhino Service Bus with "Store and Forward"

Tags: c#, rhino-servicebus, rhino-esb

Is it possible to use Rhino Service Bus with Rhino Queues in a 'store and forward' configuration?

For example, lets say I have two nodes, `A` and `B`. If node `B` is down, I don't want any of the messages that node `A` is trying to send to `B` to be lost - so `A` should cache outbound messages in a durable, local queue before attempting to send them to the remote queue.

Is this possible when using Rhino Service Bus with Rhino Queues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over on the [Rhino Tools Dev](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rhino-tools-dev/7N8h96D6wk0) groups I heard back from Corey Kaylor (who is on the development team for both Rhino Queues and Rhino Service Bus), who said this is actually the only bahaviour that is supported with Rhino Queues.